# Found an error in font in Ubuntu, where and how should I report it?

Tags: fonts, unicode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

I am playing with Braille Unicode characters and I just realised that DejaVuSans Mono and FreeMono (and maybe other fonts too) show character:

> ⡳ U+2873 BRAILLE PATTERN DOTS-12567

as

> ⡣ U+2863 BRAILLE PATTERN DOTS-1267

(they both look the same in Character map, or if used in text)

Dot no 5 is missing.

Should I report it somewhere? Where?

Comment: Please see [this question.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

run command:

```
ubuntu-bug ttf-dejavu-core
```

and follow instructions.